# Compiling Oniguruma regex library to javascript using Emscripten

Tags: javascript, emscripten, oniguruma

I'm trying to get a more powerful regex library into javascript. The only solution I found is to compile [Oniguruma regex library](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) to javascript using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten)

I've installed Emscripten and tested it with their small test scripts, also downloaded oniguruma source code, but still don't know what should be done next.

Anyone familiar with emscripten?

Comment: don't understand the down votes! did I do anything wrong? is the question not suitable for stackoverflow or the tags are inappropriate? what's wrong?

Comment: It's too specific, and not attractive to other users. It's more suitable to be asked in emscripten's mail list.

Comment: having better regular expressions in the world's most widely distributed programming language is anything but 'unattractive', rather, it is a highly relevant endeavor.

Comment: yeah; other users? You mean the majority? the ones looking for "how to sum an array in JavaScript" and other extremely innocuous questions?

Comment: Hey Allen, have you managed to compile the oniguruma with emscripten?

Comment: Nope! moved to another solution. I would love to be able to get a better regex inside browser

Answer (score 1):

When you utilize *Emscripten*, the general way of building/compiling from C/C++ stays similar. The steps which change, are that you don't use e.g. the *gcc compiler* but *Emscripten compiler*.

That said there is the general question of whether you are familiar with *C/C++* and more specific with *autotools* (which seems like the build tool *Oniguruma* uses). If you are not, you will probably have a very hard time understanding what needs to be done and how.

Last I checked *Emscripten* did not have support for *Libtool*, so building, utilizing *autotools*, will probably fail. Feel free to ask at *Emscripten* IRC channel though, whether this is indeed not possible.

Another way I can think of is using *autotools* to generate *Makefiles* and then writing custom targets for *Emscripten* programs. Beware that this is for advanced users, familiar with the *make* cruft.

If these steps are to taxing for you perhaps you should see whether a Javascript library can be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 0):

A more realistic approach to do this is going to be to use http://xregexp.com. It adds many more features to RegExps and compiles them down to JavaScripts more limited RegExp dialect so it can get the best of both features and performance. Compiling a regexp library using emscripten is very unlikely to be performant enough to use in production. For some uses, emscripten is excellent, but in this case it seems like the overhead is going to be not worth the cost.

The author of XRegExp even has an article on lookbehinds http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind

Comment: If you make claims, please back them up. Why shouldn't _Emscripten_ compiled code be as fast as "natively written" Javascript? In the end it is only Javascript to begin with.

Comment: Because it's not emscripten compiled code vs. native javascript. It's emscripten compiled code vs. something built into the engine and not iplemented in javascript at all. I'm talking about the builtin RegExp here, not something implemented in js.

Comment: then you should also add the requirement, under which your statement is true. That is - only if the RegEx can be expressed in the Javascript variant. Only then can one _assume_ it is faster.

Comment: I've tried XRegExp and it doesn't cut it. What I want is to parse a lot of complex regexes written originally for Ruby 1.9 in a client side chrome app environment. The size and speed does not matter but being able to parse all regexes correctly is what I'm after.